# SQL AES_Encrypt col with PHP instance

Tags: php, sql

Is it possible to have a column in on of your tables to AES_ENCRYPT any values that you insert into the table, Or can this only be done with PHP using prepared statements or PDO?

So instead of a query do the encryption, is it possible for SQL to encrypt the value before the insert.

e.g. php query

```
Query: INSERT INTO table (Name, Surname, Age) VALUES (John, Doe, 58)
```

and on SQL instead of inserting the values you insert the encrypted values

```
VALUES(AES_ENCRYPT('John', 'Key'), AES_ENCRYPT('Doe', 'Key'), AES_ENCRYPT('58', 'key')
```

Anyone with any ideas or is this not at all possible.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? ANSI SQL has no AES_ENCRYPT.

Comment: Stuff like this is defintiely DBMS Specific. Tell us which DBMS you are thinking of using

Comment: Microsoft SQL Express